# ImportError for selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium, python-import

Python 3.4: I have installed selenium using this command on my Ubuntu:

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

However, when I try to import, I get an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
```

Error - 
`File "./selenium.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import web driver`

If I try to install the package again. it says it is already installed. I can see the package here, I can also see the webdriver directory there:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium-2.47.1.egg-info`

This path is in my Python 3.4 environment variable. I have this working on my mac (Python3.4) but does not work on Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you naming the script you're running `selenium`? I suspect it is importing itself, rather than the globally installed `selenium` module. Use a different name so that you don't shadow the existing module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from the error message -

> File **"./selenium.py"**, line 2, in module 
>      from selenium import web driver

you have named your file - `selenium.py` - this is masking the library module `selenium` , which is causing the issue.

You should rename your file to something else, such that it does not mask any libraries.

Also, in the code you pasted, there is no space between `web` and `driver` but in the error message there seems to be a space, if the space is really there in the code, then remove the space as well. It should be -

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a space in `web driver`. Please change it to `webdriver`.

```
Error - File "./selenium.py", line 2, in <module>
from selenium import web driver
```

Also, your file is named selenium and your module is named selenium. These two names are conflicting.